# file to byte[] reading incorrectly

Tags: java, java-io

I am saving/reading an array of bytes. When I print the bytes being saved, they are all the correct values, but when I read them there are 3 random negative numbers between every byte saved, and there are a bunch of extra random values at the end of the bytes, and all negative numbers are gone.

Read code:

```
byte[] tmpData = new byte[(int) file.length()];
try {
    tmpData = IOUtil.readFully(file);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

IOUtil.readFully

```
public static byte[] readFully(File file) throws IOException {
    Checks.notNull(file, "File");
    Checks.check(file.exists(), "Provided file does not exist!");
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
    Throwable var2 = null;

    byte[] var8;
    try {
        long length = file.length();
        if (length > 2147483647L) {
            throw new IOException("Cannot read the file into memory completely due to it being too large!");
        }

        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
        int offset = 0;

        int numRead;
        for(boolean var7 = false; offset < bytes.length && (numRead = is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length - offset)) >= 0; offset += numRead) {
            ;
        }

        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            throw new IOException("Could not completely read file " + file.getName());
        }

        is.close();
        var8 = bytes;
    } catch (Throwable var12) {
        var2 = var12;
        throw var12;
    } finally {
        $closeResource(var2, is);
    }

    return var8;
}
```

Writing code:

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(path, false));
int[] data = new int[] { 19,0,0,0,0,28,1,1,28,2,1,36,1,1,31,0,2,-1,0,2 }
for(int bytes : data) { writer.write(bytes); }
```

Read bytes:
10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 28, 10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 28, 10, 2, 10, 1, 10, 36, 10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 31, 10, 0, 10, 2, 10, -17, -65, -65, 10, 0, 10
Data in file (opened with Notepad++)
blank line, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 1, 1, 28, 2, 1, $, 1, 1, 31, 0, 2, ï¿¿, 0, 2
Earlier for some reason negative numbers that weren't written to the file were read.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others which shows that there are random bytes in the file either stored or read from your code.

Comment: Keep in mind that `Writer` are meant for writing characters/texts, not for writing "binary" data. You might want to use `FileOutputStream` objects to write "binary" data to a file.

Comment: I checked the file myself and it looked, FileOutputStream will probably fix the lack of negatives but what about the reading?

Comment: The reading is not wrong in principle, but it needs to be symmetric with the writing in some sense, so actually write *plain bytes* (eg `Files.write(path, bytes)`) since that is what you're reading.

Comment: Reader and Writer are designed for text so binary data can get mangled by the character encoding used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the standard library (`import java.nio.file.Files;`).

```
byte[] tmpData = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
```

and

```
Files.write(file.toPath(), bytes);
```

Comment: Files didn't change anything, still outprinted 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 28, 10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 28, 10, 2, 10, 1, 10, 36, 10, 1, 10, 1, 10, 31, 10, 0, 10, 2, 10, -17, -65, -65, 10, 0, 10,

Comment: @Big_Bad_E make sure the data you are writing is `byte[]` not `int[]` and write it with `Files.write`.